# Meaning of phrase "knock against sth."

Tags: phrases, expressions, idioms

I have encountered the phrase "... the knock against [sth.]" from [this reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/investing/comments/9at6tp/chases_new_you_invest_trading_platform_is_up_and/e4y50sf/). Does this mean that the person has concerns or problem with [sth.]? Is this expression used commonly?

The full sentence was:

> The only knock I have against Robinhood is their inferior research tools. Otherwise I have had no issues with them.

Comment: What do you THINK it means, from the context?  Do any of the [dictionary definitions](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/knock) seem to fit?

Comment: From the context, I guess it does mean to have discomfort or problem with something, but I'm not sure how this expression is normally used. Could not find a proper definition from [online dictionaries](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/knock+against), where 'knock' is used as a verb, where here it's used as a noun.

Comment: So you didn't follow the link I gave you?  Or look at the other dictionaries you find when you Google `define knock`?

Comment: Oops my bad. Just found this entry ": a harsh and often petty criticism". Thanks for sharing though.

Comment: By *sth* do you mean *something*? Because *sth* isn't used anywhere in the quotation you give. If you mean *something*, please use the actual word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to **knock**    [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/104090?rskey=HZ0vvg&result=4&isAdvanced=false#eid)

> Sense: To speak ill or slightingly of, disparage, **find fault with**,
>   criticize captiously

As in:

> Observer 22 Sept.    It's fashionable nowadays to ‘knock’ England for
>   its shortcomings.